# nginx: How to match server with shorter regex first when both have the same TLD?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to support two server name schemes.

Current: https://custid.hosted-environment.com/test/app-name/
Proposed: https://app-name.test.custid.hosted-environment.com

The current scheme works just fine, but trying to support both the current and proposed scheme and have nginx direct to the correct server based on the host does not seem to be working.

Here is an abbreviated version of the config I'm using, I've tried to trim it down to just the parts that are relevent:

```
http {
  server {
    listen       443        ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443   ssl http2;

    server_name  ~^(?<app_custid>[^.]+)(?<app_domain>.hosted-environment.com)$;

    root /opt/nginx/apps/;

    location ~ ^/(?<app_env>dev|test|prod)/(?<app_name>app-name)/server(?<request_path>.*) {
      include /opt/nginx/config/nginx/proxy.conf;
      proxy_pass  https://backend_server;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?<app_env>dev|test|prod)/(?<app_name>app-name)(?<request_path>.*) {
      ssi on;
      ssi_types *;

      root /opt/nginx/;

      try_files
                /apps/$app_env/$app_name/dist/client/$request_path
                /apps/$app_env/$app_name/dist/client/index.html
                =404;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen       443        ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443   ssl http2;

    server_name  ~^(?<app_name>[^.]+)\.(?<app_env>dev|test|prod)\.(?<app_custid>[^.]+)(?<app_domain>.hosted-environment.com)$;

    root /opt/nginx/;

    location ~ ^/server(?<request_path>.*) {
      include /opt/nginx/config/nginx/proxy.conf;
      proxy_pass  https://backend_server;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?<request_path>.*) {
      root /opt/nginx/;

      try_files
                /apps/$origin_env/$origin_app_name/dist/client/$request_path
                /apps/$origin_env/$origin_app_name/dist/client/index.html
                =404;
    }
  }
}
```

With this config, whichever `server` block I put first is the one that will handle the request. How can I make nginx use the correct server block based on the host?